# Seg Fault (Whats Wrong, strcpy)

Tags: c++

In GDB I get:

```
 
(gdb) backtrace
0  0xb7d91544 in strcpy () from /lib/libc.so.6
1  0x08048982 in ISBN::ISBN(char const*, ISBNPrefix&) ()
2  0x08048d4a in main ()
(gdb)
```

From this code:

```
ISBN::ISBN(const char* str, ISBNPrefix& list) {
    if(isValid(str)) {
            isSet = true;
            sprintf(*isbnStr,"%s",str);
    }
}
```

What exactly would be causing this?

isbnStr is created in the header:

```
class ISBN
{
 ...
    char* isbnStr[11];
 ...
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing here to cause this seg fault?

The call in main is:

```
ISBN* isbn = new ISBN("7999999008",*prefix);
```

Comment: As an aside, according to Wikipedia, ISBNs assigned in 2007 and later have 13 digits and not 10.

Comment: Thanks, the program will be processing 100 records at a time and I don't have any plans to accept new ISBNs yet, but good to know if I do expand this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

isbnStr is an array of strings (or more specifically character pointers), not an array of characters. I think you meant to do `char isbnStr[11];`

Comment: And to follow up on that, `sprintf(*isbnStr,"%s",str);` should be `strncpy(isbnStr, str, sizeof(isbnStr));`

Comment: @rlibby: Never use `strncpy` without explicitly setting the last character to nul.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything to initialize `isbnStr`?  If not, it is probably an invalid pointer and that can cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy the string at `str` (a `char*`) into `isbnStr[0]` (a `char*`), but while `isbnStr` is a valid a array of 11 `char*`, those `char*`s are uninitialized and pointing to garbage addresses. Allocate memory for `isbnStr[0]` through `isbnStr[10]`.

Note: I'm assuming you *do* mean to have isbnStr being an array of 11 `char*`s, for whatever reason. If you want `isbnStr` to be an array of 11 characters, declare it as `char isbnStr[11]` and don't dereference `isbnStr` in your `sprintf`.